# baseline of two text views in Android

Tags: android, textview

I have tow Textviews and i try to aling  second textview to top of a first Textview
this is a my source

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:clickable="true"
android:orientation="vertical">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="bottom">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/u_major_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="25"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="40dp"
            android:singleLine="true"

            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/u_minor_text_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="top|left">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/u_minor_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:text="12" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

[this is a result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGgpg.png)

maybe problem is  text size.it is a possible to change second Textview's possition . i want both texts to BaseLine(not textviews)
if anyone knows solution please help me
thanks

Comment: What is the result you are expecting?

Comment: @Jas http://i.stack.imgur.com/SZfMw.png this result,

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:clickable="true"
              android:orientation="vertical">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_weight="0.90">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/u_major_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="25"
                android:textSize="40dp"

                />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="0.10">

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.11">
            </FrameLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/u_minor_text_container"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.90"
                android:gravity="top|left">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/u_minor_text"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:text="12"
                    android:textSize="16dp"/>
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Result**

[image: img1]

Comment: thanks your result i s perfect but if i change first text size for example 40dp change to 50 dp-- design also changed @Aspicas.it is a possible to recieve  thios result all text size?

Comment: Do you have any idea? @Aspicas

Comment: It should found with another "similar" size, but you always need to change `weights` from a `FrameLayout` for a perfect design... and try to use `match_parent`

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:clickable="true"
android:orientation="vertical">


<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="bottom">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/u_major_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="25"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:singleLine="true"

        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/u_minor_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:textSize="16dp"
     android:layout_above="@+id/u_major_text"
        android:text="12" />
</RelativeLayout>
```